# Forward Soap UI request through proxifier

Tags: soapui, tunneling

I am using proxifier to tunnel my requests, how can I forward my soap UI request to proxifier so that I can test my web service?
The IP address of the webservice has been already added in the proxification rules in proxifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt find the solution but I was able to find an alternate.

Its an add on to **Mozzilla FireFox**, The add on name is **Soa Client** .

To add this add on, just go to tools, click on adds on and search the soa client.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem with SoapUI-x64-4.6.4.exe, Windows 7 x64 and Sun Java 1.6 x64 
Try to download  SoapUI-4.6.4-windows-bin.zip unzip and run using bat file.
This version works through proxifier.

Answer (score 0):

According to Proxifier's [documentation](http://www.proxifier.com/documentation/v3/):

> Proxifier allows you to:
>
> Run any network applications through a proxy server. No special configuration is required for the software; the entire process is completely **transparent**.

I would ask the question - how you misconfigured proxifier - check its documentation.

Comment: Hi,  Proxifier is working well at my end. Theres a particular IP to which I am hitting, when I hit through putty it goes from proxifier, same with firefox. but when I access the same IP address from soap UI, its not going through proxifier and hence I am unable to connect to that server using soap UI

Comment: According to Proxifier's documentation the application does not know it is there and does not need to change - therefore you may have found a bug in Proxifier. 
I would suggest re-starting SoapUI once just to be sure it is not a stupid problem like the connection is already open

Comment: Thanks ronk, but the issue is still there and its with some of my colleagues too who are working with both.. Have tried restarting but wasnt able to use it, then I am using soa client which is an add on in mozzila firefox, working for now :)